# How to catch SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN code in Windows Service Program

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I’m working on programming a Windows service program recently.

The problem I faced with while programming is that Windows OS doesn’t turn off normally when I install my program on it. It takes too long time to turn off the system. It seems my program is the cause for the problem.

I tried to find a solution on the internet, and I found adding ‘SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN’ to my code can be the solution. I did so, but **my program doesn’t catch ‘SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN’ and I don’t know why…**

Does anyone know why it is so… and can anyone tell me how to fix it?
Thanks.

I put a snippet from my code below.

```
// method that sets service status. 
void SvcSetStatus(DWORD dwState, DWORD dwAccept = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP | SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN )
        {
            SERVICE_STATUS ss;
            ss.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
            ss.dwCurrentState = dwState;
            ss.dwControlsAccepted = dwAccept;
            ss.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
            ss.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
            ss.dwCheckPoint = 0;
            ss.dwWaitHint = 0;


            g_NowState = dwState; 
            SetServiceStatus(g_hSrv, &ss);

        }

// method of service handler 
void SvcHandler(DWORD fdwControl)
        {

            if (fdwControl == g_NowState)
            {
                return;

            }

            switch (fdwControl)
            {
                case SERVICE_CONTROL_PAUSE:

                    break;
                case SERVICE_CONTROL_CONTINUE:

                    break;
                case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:
                    ShutdownService(FALSE);
                    break;
                case SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE:
                    break;
                case SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN:

                    ShutdownService(TRUE); //???
                    break;
                case SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN:

                    ShutdownService(TRUE); //service finalize function (parameter is for shutdown or not)

                    break;
                default:
                    SvcSetStatus(g_NowState);
                    break;

            }
        }
```

Comment: The *best* solution is to stop telling Windows that you want shutdown notification, i.e., leave out SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN.  If that doesn't work, or is unacceptable, you'll need to provide us with an [MCVE].  The problem isn't in the code you've posted.

Comment: You need to respond to SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP. Why you code uses ShutdownService(FALSE); for it and ShutdownService(TRUE); for others?

Comment: if param is FALSE, terminate all process , TRUE , just termintate service process.

Comment: @cha: a Stop is a different operation than a Shutdown. Maybe `ShutdownService()` skips certain operations during a true shutdown, which could explain the input parameter value. Even Microsoft says: "*services should complete their cleanup tasks as quickly as possible. It is a good practice to minimize unsaved data by saving data on a regular basis, keeping track of the data that is saved to disk, and only saving your unsaved data on shutdown. **Because the computer is being shut down, do not spend time releasing allocated memory or other system resources**.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem I faced with while programming is that Windows OS doesn’t turn off normally when I install my program on it. It takes too long time to turn off the system. It seems my program is the cause for the problem.

This usually means that you are not reporting status correctly during SCM stop/shutdown requests.  You did not show your code for `ShutdownService()`, but given the way you have coded `SvcHandler()`, make sure that `ShutdownService()` calls `SvcSetStatus(SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)` periodically while the service is in the process of stopping, and calls `SvcSetStatus(SERVICE_STOPPED)` once the service has fully stopped.

Also, another possible cause of the hang could be if your service has created a top-level `HWND` for itself and its window procedure is not responding to unhandled messages correctly, such as by calling `DefWindowProc()`.  During shutdown, certain messages get broadcasted to top-level windows, even in service processes, and they need to be responded to.

Comment: Hi. Any chance I can get a working example please. I am also getting failure for Shutdown/Pre-shutdown event: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65849013/windows-c-service-not-writing-to-file-in-preshutdown-event