# Windows service does not capture shutdown event C/C++

Tags: c++, c, winapi, events, service

I created a small windows service to capture some events, including the system shutdown. Every time I turn off the computer, the service event is not called. But when I restart the computer the event works normally.

I already tried to use: `SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN` + `SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN` and was not successful.

How could I catch the computer shutdown event?

Ps: After compiling I register the service with the following command: *sc.exe create "ZSimpleService" binPath = "C:\path\ZSimpleService.exe"*

**Edit 1:** I'm using windows 10

**Code:**

```
SERVICE_STATUS g_ServiceStatus = { 0 };
SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE g_StatusHandle = NULL;
HANDLE g_ServiceStopEvent = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

VOID WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv);
DWORD WINAPI ServiceWorkerThread(LPVOID lpParam);
DWORD WINAPI CtrlHandlerEx(DWORD CtrlCode, DWORD eventType, LPVOID eventData, LPVOID context);

#define SERVICE_NAME _T("ZSimpleService")

VOID WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv) {

    g_StatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx(SERVICE_NAME, CtrlHandlerEx,
    NULL);

    if (g_StatusHandle == NULL) {
        goto EXIT;
    }

    // Tell the service controller we are starting
    ZeroMemory( & g_ServiceStatus, sizeof(g_ServiceStatus));

    g_ServiceStatus.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP
            | SERVICE_ACCEPT_POWEREVENT | SERVICE_ACCEPT_SESSIONCHANGE
            | SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_START_PENDING;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;

    if (SetServiceStatus(g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE) {
        //...
    }

    g_ServiceStopEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

    if (g_ServiceStopEvent == NULL) {
        //...
        goto EXIT;
    }

    g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;

    if (SetServiceStatus(g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE) {
        //...
    }

    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ServiceWorkerThread, NULL, 0, NULL);

    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(g_ServiceStopEvent);

    g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 3;

    if (SetServiceStatus(g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE) {

    }

    EXIT: return;
}

void suspending() {
    FILE *file = fopen("C:\\test\\suspending.txt", "w+");
    if (file)
        fprintf(file, "...");
}

void logoff() {
    FILE *file = fopen("C:\\test\\logoff.txt", "w+");
    if (file)
        fprintf(file, "...");
}

void lock_session() {
    FILE *file = fopen("C:\\test\\lock_session.txt", "w+");
    if (file)
        fprintf(file, "...");
}

void poweroff() {
    FILE *file = fopen("C:\\test\\poweroff.txt", "w+");
    if (file)
        fprintf(file, "...");
}

DWORD WINAPI CtrlHandlerEx(DWORD CtrlCode, DWORD eventType, LPVOID eventData,
        LPVOID context) {
    switch (CtrlCode) {

    case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP: {
        g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOP_PENDING;
        g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
        g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
        g_ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint = 0;

        if (SetServiceStatus(g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus) == FALSE) {
            //...
        }

        SetEvent(g_ServiceStopEvent);

        return NO_ERROR;
    }
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_POWEREVENT: {
        if (eventType == PBT_APMQUERYSUSPEND) {
            //Computer is suspending
            suspending();

        }
        return NO_ERROR;
    }
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE: {
        switch (eventType) {
        case WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF:
            //User is logging off
            logoff();
            break;
        case WTS_SESSION_LOCK:
            //User locks the session
            lock_session();
            break;
        }
        return NO_ERROR;
    }
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN: {
        //Computer is shutting down
        poweroff();

        return NO_ERROR;
    }
    default:
        return ERROR_CALL_NOT_IMPLEMENTED;
    }

}

DWORD WINAPI ServiceWorkerThread(LPVOID lpParam) {

    while (WaitForSingleObject(g_ServiceStopEvent, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0) {

        //many cool code....

        Sleep(3000);
    }

    return 0;
}

DWORD RunService() {
    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY serviceTable[] = { { SERVICE_NAME, ServiceMain },
            { 0, 0 } };

    if (StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(serviceTable)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        DWORD erro = GetLastError();

        //handler erro...

        return 1;
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[]) {
    RunService();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: may be your computer really not shutdown but hibernate

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193213/how-to-catch-service-control-shutdown-code-in-windows-service-program

Comment: I shutdown windows 1903 from command line: `shutdown /s`. It works for me (create logoff.txt and poweroff.txt). How do you shutdown the machine and what's your windows version?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT hello, I tried it with the shutdown command and it worked! But I don't understand why in: start menu -> shutdown / restart -> shutdown. Shutdown does not work, alias when I shutdown the computer `CtrlHandlerEx` receives: `CtrlCode SERVICE_CONTROL_POWEREVENT` and `eventType PBT_APMQUERYSUSPEND`

Comment: From Event viewer found that shut down menu seems calling `SetSuspendState` API to put the machine to sleep mode so you don't get `SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the **fast startup** option enabled, click start menu -> shutdown will put the machine into sleep mode/hibernation instead of shutdown. But restart menu isn't affected. (And shuting down from command line isn't affected too as we already found.)

So you can disable fast startup to solve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Thank very much! Perfect solution! :D

Comment: How can I capture shutdown when this option is checked? We should still be able to capture the hibernate / sleep and have the service capture it.